# Why won't my old laptop with Vista connect to the Internet?

Tags: router, laptop, windows-vista

I have received an older Compaq Presario laptop (Vista) which won't go out to the internet.  The Network Connection sees the Netgear N600 router, says connected, signal strength excellent, but internet won't load wirelessly.

The laptop will connect if directly connected to router by Ethernet cable. Other laptop, desktop and tablets all run well with this wireless router.

Have no idea how to change something in the laptop to solve this problem.  Netgear support would not help unless I bought a $150 support package.  Can someone please help.

Comment: Do you get valid ip after on Wireless interface after you connect to it ?

Comment: This it pretty broad. There could be so many things causing this issue. Considering the age of the PC and the OS being used, I am inclined to believe it has something to do with the drivers or security incompatibility. Have you installed all updated drivers, Windows Updates and even system BIOS?

Comment: Is it really not getting to the Internet, or is it a browser problem? Try to ping something like `8.8.8.8` to see if the Internet connection works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try connecting the laptop to a different wireless network?

Also, check the IP ([you can see directions here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-find-your-pcs-ip-address-in-windows-vista.html)). If the IP is like 169.XXX.XXX.XXX then you have to set it manually.

Comment: Thanks for contributing to superuser! This might have been better as a comment, since it is a request for more information from the question author.